# Requests not downloading full PDF from Google Drive

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to download all the PDF slides hosted on a google drive. The urls collected point to a Google Drive that redirect to the PDF. When I try downloading a PDF using requests, it only download the HTML (122 KB) and not the binary data.

```
import os, sys, time, random
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://mila.umontreal.ca/en/cours/deep-learning-summer-school-2017/slides'

def download(url, name):
    response = requests.get(url)
    pdf = response.content
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(pdf)

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
browser.switch_to_frame(browser.find_element_by_class_name('iframe-class'))
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.flip-entry a')
titles = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.flip-entry-title')
pdfs = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in links]
names = [title.text for title in titles]
browser.quit()

for i, pdf in enumerate(pdfs):    download(pdf, names[i])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you the links you are extracting are view links and download links. So when you download that link you get an HTML of google driver which would then load the file using Javascript in the browser. Then it shows a download button for you to download the file

So you need to add code to change your view link to a download link

```
for i, pdf in enumerate(pdfs):
    # get the doc id
    doc_id = pdf.split("/")[-2]
    download_url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id={}&export=download".format(doc_id)
    download(download_url, names[i])
```

Comment: Thanks. Works with slight tweak (use http instead of https).